# S3: while setting up the S3 for created SNS topic, getting the API error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, events, notifications, amazon-sns

i am trying to setting up the notification for the event of put, post events on s3 bucket. not able to do it
[image]

Comment: Hi. Also noticed that you have a lot of questions with answers, yet non was accepted. I would suggest reviewing them and accept helpful answers as this is good practice and helps others.

Answer (score 6):

Before subscribing an SNS topic to S3 event notifications, you must specify a topic policy [AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-policy.html) with the appropriate permissions. That topic policy must exist before you create the subscription.

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "example-ID",
    "Statement": [
    {
    "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS":"*"  
    },
    "Action": [
        "SNS:Publish"
    ],
    "Resource": "SNS-topic-ARN",
    "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": { "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:bucket-name" },
        "StringEquals": { "aws:SourceAccount": "bucket-owner-account-id" }
    }
    }
    ]
    }
```

More information can be found in the docs [Configure a bucket for notifications (SNS topic or SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html#step1-create-sns-topic-for-notification)